# mongod killed by OOM kill: "Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 20391 (mongod) score 993 or sacrifice child"

Tags: linux, mongodb, out-of-memory, oom

mongod killed by OOM kill: "Memory cgroup out of memory"
The machine has 32GB RAM, but the OOM kills the mongod process when it has 7GB RAM in use.

```
[11988.010379] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 16392 (mongod) score 994 or sacrifice child
[11988.022403] Killed process 16392 (mongod) total-vm:9016932kB, anon-rss:7284224kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[11988.319261] oom_reaper: reaped process 16392 (mongod), now anon-rss:4kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[15015.365245] conn2096 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14000c0(GFP_KERNEL), nodemask=(null),  order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[15015.379050] conn2096 cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[15015.385647] CPU: 3 PID: 15357 Comm: conn2096 Not tainted 4.14.285-147.501.amzn1.x86_64 #1
[15015.397908] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.11.amazon 08/24/2006
[15015.407529] Call Trace:
[15015.411779]  dump_stack+0x66/0x81
[15015.417104]  dump_header+0x94/0x21a
[15015.422586]  oom_kill_process+0x223/0x410
[15015.428918]  out_of_memory+0x102/0x4c0
[15015.434991]  mem_cgroup_out_of_memory+0x3b/0x60
[15015.442077]  mem_cgroup_oom_synchronize+0x2d8/0x310
[15015.449609]  ? mem_cgroup_css_reset+0xd0/0xd0
[15015.456520]  pagefault_out_of_memory+0xf/0x60
[15015.463452]  __do_page_fault+0x4ae/0x4c0
[15015.469099]  ? page_fault+0x2f/0x50
[15015.472734]  page_fault+0x45/0x50
[15015.476267] RIP: 4420b8a8:0x5627db743000
[15015.480385] RSP: 0000:00007f197f53d6d0 EFLAGS: 00489d23
[15015.480411] Task in /mongod killed as a result of limit of /mongod
[15015.491635] memory: usage 7340032kB, limit 7340032kB, failcnt 2404739
[15015.497460] memory+swap: usage 7340028kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
[15015.503577] kmem: usage 38324kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
[15015.515250] Memory cgroup stats for /mongod: cache:488KB rss:7300704KB rss_huge:0KB shmem:0KB mapped_file:264KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:0KB active_anon:7301024KB inactive_file:456KB active_file:52KB unevictable:4KB
[15015.543894] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[15015.555451] [ 3991]   498  3991  2281830  1826804    3980      11        0             0 mongod
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution:
**Edit the cgroup limitation to 50% of the machine memory (RAM).**

Long story:

I had a guess:

Cgroup limitation VS mongo limitation cause this issue:

1. cgroup limitation is 7GB (Tha was the default on the machine)
2. Mongo limitation is (total_mem/2 -1) = (32/2 -1) = 15GB, See: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/
3. mongo tries to use up to 15 GB, but linux kills it at 7GB because of the cgroup limitation

See the cgroup limitation with the command:
`cat /etc/cgconfig.conf`

```
mount {
    cpuset  = /cgroup/cpuset;
    cpu     = /cgroup/cpu;
    cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
    memory  = /cgroup/memory;
    devices = /cgroup/devices;
  }

  group mongod {
    perm {
      admin {
        uid = mongod;
        gid = mongod;
      }
      task {
        uid = mongod;
        gid = mongod;
      }
    }
    memory {
      memory.limit_in_bytes = 7G;
      }
  }
```

**To solve this, edit the cgroup limitation to 50% of the machine memory (RAM).**

To edit the cgroup limitation follow the link below (2. mongodb memory and cgroups)

Helpful links:

1. How mongo use memory:
   https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-does-mongodb-consume-and-use-memory_594704
2. mongodb memory and cgroups:
   https://vikoky.medium.com/limit-mongodb-memory-usage-using-cgroup-on-linux-a71a1888ef1c

Comment: Thank you. Please be aware that the document you link at number 2 has a malformed string assigned to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT which I think should be "”quiet cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1" and after you do a successfull update-grub you should also reboot or the next steps in the guide will not work as described.